# stop calling function for button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Please help on how to stop all buttons from calling function:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
                string script = "$(document).ready(function () {$('[id*=Button1]').click(); });";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may stop bubbling (propagation) to call [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

You may stop default actions (do not go to new page on link clicks) by calling [`prevntDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)